# cordova-plugin-firebase notifications working on Google Firebase console but not on API

Tags: api, cordova, firebase, cordova-plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using the cordova-plugin-firebase plugin, I can only get device notifications via the Google Firebase console, and not through the server http API.

APP: cordova (6.4.0) default app, not changed, with plugin cordova-plugin-firebase (0.1.21) added.

Steps to reproduce

- Download APP to device (android phone)
- Start APP (seems like this is required to register this app with the phone)
- Close APP
- Send message from server through FCM http API

  ```
       { notification:
           { title: 'Notification Test',
           body: 'Notification Test Body Text' },
           to: '/topics/all',
         priority: 'high' }
  ```
- Device does not receive/show a notification was received.

Is there a bug in the server script?

- No. If I replace cordova-plugin-firebase with cordova-plugin-fcm, then the device (and APP) receive notifications through the API just fine.

Why not just use cordova-plugin-fcm then?

- cordova-plugin-fcm is not well maintained, and I would like to use the Analytics in cordova-plugin-firebase

Comment: Seems like this is an issue with the cordova-plugin-firebase library. Possibly some additional setups are needed? Have you tried filing for an issue on the library's page?

Comment: Yes, I have submitted a question to the library's page. I posted here also because I find it peculiar that where the message is generated (API vs Console) matters. I would think the notification communication between Firebase and the device would be identical no matter the origin of the message. Obviously there is a difference, and I'm hoping someone knows what that is.